# Syntax for counting greater than and summing a value with multiple joins without the keyword having

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, count

I'm learning `SQL (Postgres)` and I'm slightly confused about something I'm trying to do.

I have the following tables. Employee:

```
  fname   | minit |  lname  |    ssn    |   bdate    |         address         | sex |  salary  | super_ssn | dno 
----------+-------+---------+-----------+------------+-------------------------+-----+----------+-----------+-----
 James    | E     | Borg    | 888665555 | 1937-11-10 | 450 Stone, Houston TX   | M   | 55000.00 |           |   1
 John     | B     | Smith   | 123456789 | 1965-01-09 | 731 Fondren, Houston TX | M   | 30000.00 | 333445555 |   5
 Franklin | T     | Wong    | 333445555 | 1955-12-08 | 638 Voss, Houston TX    | M   | 40000.00 | 888665555 |   5
 Alicia   | J     | Zelaya  | 999887777 | 1968-01-19 | 3321 Castle, Spring TX  | F   | 25000.00 | 987654321 |   4
 Jennifer | S     | Wallace | 987654321 | 1941-06-20 | 291 Berry, Bellaire TX  | F   | 43000.00 | 888665555 |   4
 Ramesh   | K     | Narayan | 666884444 | 1962-09-15 | 975 Fire Oak, Humble TX | M   | 38000.00 | 333445555 |   5
 Joyce    | A     | English | 453453453 | 1972-07-31 | 5631 Rice, Houston TX   | F   | 25000.00 | 333445555 |   5
 Ahmad    | V     | Jabbar  | 987987987 | 1969-03-29 | 980 Dallas, Houston TX  | M   | 25000.00 | 987654321 |   4
```

Project:

```
      pname      | pnumber | plocation | dnum 
-----------------+---------+-----------+------
 ProductX        |       1 | Bellaire  |    5
 ProductY        |       2 | Sugarland |    5
 ProductZ        |       3 | Houston   |    5
 Computerization |      10 | Stafford  |    4
 Reorganization  |      20 | Houston   |    1
 Newbenefits     |      30 | Stafford  |    4
```

Department:

```
     dname      | dnumber |  mgr_ssn  | mgr_start  
----------------+---------+-----------+------------
 Research       |       5 | 333445555 | 1988-05-22
 Administration |       4 | 987654321 | 1995-01-01
 Headquarters   |       1 | 888665555 | 1981-06-19
```

And works_on:

```
   essn    | pno | hours 
-----------+-----+-------
 123456789 |   1 |  32.5
 123456789 |   2 |   7.5
 666884444 |   3 |  40.0
 453453453 |   1 |  20.0
 453453453 |   2 |  20.0
 333445555 |   2 |  10.0
 333445555 |   3 |  10.0
 333445555 |  10 |  10.0
 333445555 |  20 |  10.0
 999887777 |  30 |  30.0
 999887777 |  10 |  10.0
 987987987 |  10 |  35.0
 987987987 |  30 |   5.0
 987654321 |  30 |  20.0
 987654321 |  20 |  15.0
 888665555 |  20 |   0.0
```

For this, I was trying to do something slightly more complex: To create a view that has project name, department name, number of employees, and total hours worked on each project that has the criteria of more than one employee on it. I got some reading and did some basic `count(*)` and `sum(*)` but the syntax here is killing me.

This is the furthest I got after many hours trying to understand how this syntax operates:

```
SELECT 
p.pname AS "Project",
d.dname AS "Department",
count(w.essn) AS "# of Employees",
sum(w.hours) AS "Total Hours"
FROM project p JOIN works_on w
ON p.pnumber = w.pno 
JOIN department d
ON d.dnumber = p.dnum
WHERE w.essn > 1
```

That `WHERE` clause is obviously wrong. I think I've got the `JOINS` correct. How do I put these aggregate functions correctly together with all these joins? Do I need nested queries? I've found some examples using `HAVING` but I heard it's legacy, and would like to use things that are newer and fresher, but found no other examples except using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. Are those fine to use? If not, what should I use?

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a `GROUP BY` clause to make your query a valid aggregation query: that clause should include all non-aggreated columns (I also added the project number, in case two projects have the same name).

Then, you can use a `HAVING` clause to filter on projects that have more than one employee:

```
SELECT 
    p.pname AS "Project",
    d.dname AS "Department",
    COUNT(DISTINCT w.essn) AS "# of Employees",
    SUM(w.hours) AS "Total Hours"
FROM project p 
JOIN works_on w ON p.pnumber = w.pno 
JOIN department d ON d.dnumber = p.dnum
GROUP BY p.pname, d.dname, p.pnumber
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT w.essn) > 1
```

If `(essn, number)` tuples are unique in the `works` table, then you don't need `DISTINCT` in the `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT 
    p.pname AS "Project",
    d.dname AS "Department",
    COUNT(*) AS "# of Employees",
    SUM(w.hours) AS "Total Hours"
FROM project p 
JOIN works_on w ON p.pnumber = w.pno 
JOIN department d ON d.dnumber = p.dnum
GROUP BY p.pname, d.dname, p.pnumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer! It clarifies many of the questions I had and documenting/learning this by myself has been challenging. A part of my question though that didn't get answered is related to `HAVING` being a legacy keyword, so I was looking for a way to achieve that without it. Do you know a way on how that can be done and even IF this has a potential problem at all?

Comment: `HAVING` is not legacy at all! It is a legitimate part of standard SQL. All databases that I know implement it, and will continue to do so in the future.

Comment: Well, good to know. There's a lot of information pointing to many directions and it's been a challenge to separate it and properly understand it. Thanks once more for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This way is a little bit more verbose, but eliminates the `having` keyword because the where clause is conditional after the subquery aggregate processes.

Also, because you are doing a join outside the aggregate query, it should be faster because it doesn't have to group by another external column.

```
Select
    Project_Works.Project AS "Project"
    ,Project_Works.Empcnt AS "# of Employees"
    ,Project_Works.TotHrs AS "Total Hours"
    ,d.department AS "Department"
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        p.pname Project
        ,p.pnumber Pnumber
        ,count(w.essn) EmpCnt
        ,sum(w.hours) TotHrs
    FROM 
        project p INNER JOIN works_on w ON p.pnumber = w.pno 
    GROUP BY
        p.pname,p.pnumber
    ) Project_Works

    LEFT JOIN department d on Project_Works.Pnumber = d.dnumber
WHERE
    Project_Works.Empcnt > 1
```

@GMB solution is also good.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look. How would you test the performance of the different queries?